# Rendering dates in grid

Tags: sorting, extjs, grid

I have a grid that displays data along with several dates. What I currently have showing is this:

```
Month - day - name - site - misc
April - 02    - foo  - ding - dong
April - 09    - bar  - tip  - tep
May   - 10    - foo  - ding - dong
May   - 21    - ding - qwe  - rty
May   - 26    - ding - qwe  - rty
```

But what I want to show is this, with combined days and without repeating months:

```
Month - day   - name - site - misc
April - 02    - foo  - ding - dong
      - 09    - bar  - tip  - tep
May   - 10    - foo  - ding - dong
      - 21/26 - ding - qwe  - rty
```

I've tried doing this using renderer but all I've gotten so far is getting the formatting right. I can't seem to figure out how to actually get rid of the repeating months or how to combine days. Extensive googling hasn't really gotten me anywhere either.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: That's not really a rendering exercise, you're fundamentally changing the data in the grid. There needs to be a 1-1 mapping between records/rows. You should pre-process the data to get it in the right shape first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep it on the rendering side of things, you can track the last-displayed month in a variable. Only display the month if it's different than what's in the variable, and if it is, update the variable as well.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue with repeating months, now all that's left is making sure records are merged when their days follow each other

Comment: For that also you can do the same.. where you are checking the repeating months, you can add a condition that if months are same and at the same time name,site and misc are same as previous record with same month then just delete that record from grid store and change the day value of the previous record with previous day + / + deleted record day.